# 4 Rows in to 2 two with similar column attributes

Tags: mysql, python

I have this table:

| Pincode1 | Pincode2 | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 32417 | 0 | Hyd |
| 67812 | 0 | Ban |
| 0 | 72407 | Hyd |
| 0 | 77113 | Ban |

I want result like this table:

| Pincode1 | Pincode2 | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 32417 | 72407 | Hyd |
| 67812 | 77113 | Ban |

How can I do it? Can someone suggest query in Sql and Python

Comment: A max function might be a good start. What have you tried?

Comment: GROUP BY ans MAX().

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  MAX(pincode1) AS pincode1,
        MAX(pincode2) AS pincode2,
        city
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY city;
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will give the exact result you want.

```
SELECT MAX(Pincode1), MAX(Pincode2), city
FROM `your_table`
GROUP BY city
ORDER By Pincode1 ASC, Pincode2 ASC
```